# Why doesn't my "el" work in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'text!modules/index/templates/container.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, container_temp){
    var indexView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('.main_container'),
        initialize:function(){
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        },
        render:function(){
            var $this = this;
            var $el = this.el;
            $.get('/js/index/render', {}, function(data){
                var dat = JSON.parse(data);
                $this.pars = dat;
                var tpl = _.template(container_temp, dat);
                $el.html(tpl);
            });
        }
    });
    return new indexView;
});
```

Running this code  is supposed to fill $el with HTML.  However, my browser messes up at `$el.html(tpl);`.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'html'
```

To fix this, I have to do: `$($el).html(tpl);` so that jquery registers.

This seems awkward. In my past projects, I have always done it the former way, and it has always worked.

Comment: In the `get` callback, just use `$this.$el` and remove the local `$el` => `$this.$el.html(tpl)`. You've already created the closure for `this` by capturing it in the `$this` variable, so you can just use it directly (and since you're not using it more than once, it's not saving any time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.el` is a raw DOM element but the `html` method belongs to jQuery.

Try `var $el = this.$el;` in your render method:

```
render:function(){
    var $this = this;
    var $el = this.$el;
    $.get('/js/index/render', {}, function(data){
        var dat = JSON.parse(data);
        $this.pars = dat;
        var tpl = _.template(container_temp, dat);
        $el.html(tpl);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you look at your render function:

```
render:function(){
        var $this = this;
        var $el = this.el;
        $.get('/js/index/render', {}, function(data){
            var dat = JSON.parse(data);
            $this.pars = dat;
            var tpl = _.template(container_temp, dat);
            $el.html(tpl);
        });
    }
```

You explicitly assign `var $el` so the following $el equals this.el which is the raw dom element without the jQuery wrapper you usually get with $el.

Try this: `this.$el` without the `var declaration`.

So to get the $el into the $.get scope the code would look like:

```
render:function(){
    var $this = this;
    var element = this.$el;
    $.get('/js/index/render', {}, function(data){
        var dat = JSON.parse(data);
        $this.pars = dat;
        var tpl = _.template(container_temp, dat);
        element.html(tpl);
    });
}
```